# Android Studio Programming: How to keep displaying all buttons while one button is clicked?

Tags: android, button

In android studio , I want 3 buttons on top of a page and by clicking a button, it will display corresponding information page (corresponding event took place). However, when displaying corresponding information page, all 3 buttons should still appear to the users. What I mean is that users do not need to use back key if they want to use other buttons. Please can anybody suggest a way on how to do it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I suggest reading some Android tutorials and trying yourself. If you run into any *specific* problems that you cannot solve yourself, post a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: thank you for the suggestions Davidjhons, I find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with TabStrip - maybe [library similar to this one](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip). Also consider using navigation drawer. You can find and download code examples from SDK manager.

Comment: Thank you Poss, I find the answer.